# What kind of objects get serialized and why? When would I use this?

Tags: serialization

I understand what serialized is.  I simply do not know when I would use it.  I have seen the discouraged practice of session data in a database and things like that but other than that I do not know.

What kind of objects state would I save in a database, file system, anything that needs persistence?  Why would I use it for a non-"permanent" reason?

I do not have a context per se.  All I really do are client server web apps.  I may get to use a Java stack for it, but I'd really like to understand this part of things, should I need it.

I have asked similar questions. I'm just not understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a sentence, using a generic serialiser is a reasonable way to save stuff to disk, move stuff over a network in a manner which doesn't require you to design a data format, write code that emits data in that format, and write a parser for that format (all error-prone) by hand.

Any time you want to persist an object (or object hierarchy) beyond its existence inside a single execution on a single machine, you are going to want to serialise and deserialise.

Comment: Do web services use this at all?

Answer (score 0):

Some scenarios that come to my mind are

1. Caching: when you want to offload in-memory objects to disk (the caching framework can serialise the object to disk)
2. For thick clients (either a desktop application or an app using RMI) you'll need to transfer objects from one JVM to another, and this is done by serialising them

I can't think of any other scenarios from the top of my head.